# How to recursively split/flatten an object with Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, flatten

I'm trying to recursively split some kind of flatten an object if it has some values as arrays.

- If no value is an array it should return the object as is.
- If there is a value which is blank array, it should return the object as is, but replace that array value with a blank string
- If there are multiple array values, it should return flattened split of the object. For example if there is an object with arrays such as  :

```
{
    "wq": "e2201b13-aa03-4044-b4e3-1ecb25ef5083",
    "we": "2019-08-19T00:00:00",
    "er": "2019-09-18T00:00:00",
    "rt": "PAID",
    "ty": "300.00",
    "yu": "27.27",
    "ui": "272.73",
    "io": "0",
    "op": "300.00",
    "pa": "8df30d22-5af3-4d61-a420-566ccdad8cdf",
    "as": "AUD",
    "sd": false,
    "df": false,
    "fg": "2019-12-04T19:57:48",
    "gh": "2019-09-16T00:00:00",
    "hj": "0",
    "jk": [
        "6c9809af-269b-4b86-8b07-78c83a12bd18",
        "6c9809af-269b-4b86-8b07-78c83a12bd19"
    ],
    "lk": [
        '112',
        '111',
    ],
    "zx": null,
    "xc": "",
    "vb": []
}
```

It should return an Array with 4 objects, for all the permutations of those. Where the values for lk, jk and vb are strings. vb is always going to be blank since it's a blank object. It would be just the same if in the source object vb was such the '' i.e. a blank string.
4 objects because there are 2 arrays with 2 objects each. 2^2 = 4. If for example, vb had 2 objects as well, then there will be 2^3=8 objects with all other keys as same, but the mentioned 3 keys as strings.

- The values inside the arrays are not known. So, it can be an arbitrary number of od values, ranging from 0-n
- The keys in source object which can be arrays are not known. Hence it needs to recursively traverse.
- The values in source object can also be null or {} object, which can be ignored.

So far I've written a starter such that:

```
const result = [];
const reserve = {};

Object.keys(source).forEach((key) => {
    if (source[key] instanceof Object) {
        // const isArr = Array.isArray(source[key]);
        source[key].forEach((element) => {
            result.push({
                ...source,
                [key]: element
            });
        });
    } else {
        reserve[key] = source[key]
    }
})

console.log(result)
// console.log(reserve)
// console.log(result.map(i => Object.assign({}, i, reserve)))
```

It is giving me desired output to some extent but still needs work. Any recommendations and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I did come across some suggestions, but they're not giving desired output.

Comment: `but still needs work` `not giving desired output.` are not very useful use case statements

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, you like to get a cartesian product and keep empty arrays as single value, you could have an eye on this data.

You could take a recursive function which separates all key/value pairs and build a new cartesian product by iterating the values, if an array with objects call `getCartesian` again and build new objects.

```js
function getCartesian(object) {
    return Object.entries(object).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        var temp = [];
        r.forEach(s =>
            (Array.isArray(v) && v.length ? v : [v]).forEach(w =>
                (w && typeof w === 'object' && (!Array.isArray(w) || w.length) ? getCartesian(w) : [w]).forEach(x =>
                    temp.push(Object.assign({}, s, { [k]: x }))
                )
            )
        );
        return temp;
    }, [{}]);
}

var data = { wq: "e2201b13-aa03-4044-b4e3-1ecb25ef5083", we: "2019-08-19T00:00:00", er: "2019-09-18T00:00:00", rt: "PAID", ty: "300.00", yu: "27.27", ui: "272.73", io: "0", op: "300.00", pa: "8df30d22-5af3-4d61-a420-566ccdad8cdf", as: "AUD", sd: false, df: false, fg: "2019-12-04T19:57:48", gh: "2019-09-16T00:00:00", hj: "0", jk: ["6c9809af-269b-4b86-8b07-78c83a12bd18", "6c9809af-269b-4b86-8b07-78c83a12bd19"], lk: ["112", "111"], zx: null, xc: "", vb: [] };

console.log(getCartesian(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```